# Centered labels in D3 tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to add labels in the middle of the links, but I'm doing something wrong with the coordinates, although I have calculated them down in paper. The translation vector that I have obtained (excluding the fix for the arrows, which I haven't reached yet. See link update for more details) is the following:

```
x = (target.x - source.x) / 2;
y = (target.y - source.y - RECT_HEIGHT) / 2
```

What have I done wrong to get wrong positioning? It may be a problem with my understanding of the translate parameter. AFAIK, this parameter is used to move the coordinates of an object by this vector, so I calculated the vector based on this idea.

In the following snippet you can see the current state of the labels.

```js
var data = {
    "name": "Eve",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Cain",
            "link": "Link 1",
        },
        {
            "name": "Israel",
            "link": "Link 9",
        },
        {
            "name": "Sarah",
            "link": "Link 10",
        },
        {
            "name": "Seth",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enos",
                    "link": "Link 2",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Noam",
                    "link": "Link 3",
                }
            ],
            "link": "Link 4",
        },
        {
            "name": "Abel",
            "link": "Link 5",
        },
        {
            "name": "Awan",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enoch",
                    "link": "Link 6",
                }
            ],
            "link": "Link 7",
        },
        {
            "name": "Azura",
            "link": "Link 8",
        }
    ],
};

const DX = 120;
const DY = 80;

const RECT_WIDTH = 40;
const RECT_HEIGHT = 15;

const TRANSITION_DURATION = 700;
const TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION = 300;

// Zoom constants
const MIN_ZOOM = 0.15;
const MAX_ZOOM = Infinity;

// Get size available
let width = $(document).width();
let height = $(document).height();

// New tree layout with default settings. 
let tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([DX, DY]);

// Visualize links in a tree diagram rooted at the top
let diagonal = d3.linkVertical()
    .x(d => d.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2)
    .y(d => d.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2);

/* 
    Function that creates the first tree with the default layout
*/
function createRoot() {
    // Data is already in JSON format. We only need to create the hierarchy
    // based on it.
    let root = d3.hierarchy(data);
    root.x0 = DX / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
        d.id = i;
        d._children = d.children;
        if (d.depth >= 0) d.children = null;
    });
    return root;
}

/* 
    Function that updates all the nodes in a tree according to the click event
*/
function update(source) {
    const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
    const links = root.links();

    // Compute the new tree layout
    tree(root);

    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));

    /*=============================NODE SECTION============================== */
    // Obtain all the nodes
    const node = gNode.selectAll("g")
        .data(nodes, d => d.id);

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x0},${source.y0})`)
        .on("click", function (event, d) {
            if (d.children) // Node expanded -> Collapse
                collapse(d);
            else // Node collapsed -> Expand
                d.children = d._children
            update(d);
            centerNode(d);
        })

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        // Two different classes, one for the links that can be expanded and
        // another for the expanded ones or leafs.
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded")
        .attr("height", RECT_HEIGHT)
        .attr("width", RECT_WIDTH)
        
    // Inside node text
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        // The position of the text is centered 
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        // Text of the node is the name. This will change in future versions
        // to handle all the data that we want to store
        .text(d => d.data.name)
        .clone(true).lower();

    // Transition nodes to their new position (update)
    var nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
        // Smooth transition from 0 to 1 and back to 0 when expanding/collapsing
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);
    
    // Update class of rectangles
    nodeUpdate.select('rect')
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded");

    /*  Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position (that's why we use
        x and y instead of x0 and y0) */
    node.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x},${source.y})`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

    /*=============================LINK SECTION============================== */
    const link = gLink.selectAll("path")
        .data(links, d => d.target.id);

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position
    const linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)") // add the arrow to the link end
        // d attribute defines a path to be drawn
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            // Diagonal actually paints a curve line between the source and the
            // target
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position
    link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition)
        // In this case the link will be changed in order to have the arrows in
        // the correct position 
        .attr("d", d => diagonal({
            source: d.source,
            target: {
                x: d.target.x,
                y: d.target.y - RECT_HEIGHT
            }
        }));

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    link.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    const linkText = gLink.selectAll("g")
        .data(links, d => d.target.id);

    const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "linkLabel")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${source.x0 + RECT_WIDTH / 2},${source.y0 + RECT_HEIGHT / 2})`)
    
    linkTextEnter.append("text")
        .text(d => (d.target.data.link));

    linkText.merge(linkTextEnter).transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", d => 
        `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x + RECT_WIDTH) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y + RECT_HEIGHT) / 2})`)
        // Smooth transition from 0 to 1 and back to 0 when expanding/collapsing
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);

    linkText.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("transform", `translate(${source.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2},${source.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2})`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

    // Stash the old positions for transition
    root.eachBefore(d => {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

/*
    Function that centers a given node in the screen. It will be used so that
    the node that has been clicked doesn't go out of sight
*/
function centerNode(source) {
    let scale = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("svg").node()).k;
    let x = -source.x0 * scale + width / 2 - RECT_WIDTH / 2 * scale;
    let y = -source.y0 * scale + height / 2 - RECT_HEIGHT / 2 * scale;
    // Define the transition
    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));
    // Move all the nodes based on the previous parameters
    svg.transition(transition)
        .call(zoomBehaviours.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(scale));
}

/*
    Function that collapses all the subtree of a given node.
*/
function collapse(node) {
    if (node.children) { // Expanded
        node.children = null;
        node._children.forEach(collapse)
    }
}

/*
    Function that creates the possibility to add arrows to links
*/
function createArrows() {
    defs.selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 10 10`)
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
}

// Root creation
const root = createRoot();

// SVG variable that will contain all the configuration for the images.
// We need to append it to the body
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// SVG group that will contain two groups declared below
const g = svg.append("g");
    
// Two groups: One of links and another of nodes
const gLink = g.append("g");
const gNode = g.append("g");

// Zoom configuration
const zoomBehaviours = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM])
    .on('zoom', (event) => g.attr('transform', event.transform));

// Add the zoom so that svg knows that it is available
svg.call(zoomBehaviours);

// build the arrow.
let defs = svg.append("svg:defs");
createArrows();

// We need to update the root first to generate the first tree, and center it
update(root);
centerNode(root);
```

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node .notExpanded {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.2;
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node .expanded {
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node text {
    fill: black;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
    text-align: center;
    alignment-baseline: central;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}
.linkLabel {
    fill: black;
    stroke: none;
    font: 8px sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-anchor: middle;
    alignment-baseline: central;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: grab;
}
body:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already horizontally centered, you just need to remove the `RECT_HEIGHT` for adjusting the vertical position:

```
.attr("transform", d => `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x + RECT_WIDTH) / 2},
    ${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`)
```

Also, I changed `alignment-baseline` to `dominant-baseline`. Here's the result:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Eve",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Cain",
      "link": "Link 1",
    },
    {
      "name": "Israel",
      "link": "Link 9",
    },
    {
      "name": "Sarah",
      "link": "Link 10",
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Enos",
          "link": "Link 2",
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam",
          "link": "Link 3",
        }
      ],
      "link": "Link 4",
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel",
      "link": "Link 5",
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Enoch",
        "link": "Link 6",
      }],
      "link": "Link 7",
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura",
      "link": "Link 8",
    }
  ],
};

const DX = 120;
const DY = 80;

const RECT_WIDTH = 40;
const RECT_HEIGHT = 15;

const TRANSITION_DURATION = 700;
const TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION = 300;

// Zoom constants
const MIN_ZOOM = 0.15;
const MAX_ZOOM = Infinity;

// Get size available
let width = $(document).width();
let height = $(document).height();

// New tree layout with default settings. 
let tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([DX, DY]);

// Visualize links in a tree diagram rooted at the top
let diagonal = d3.linkVertical()
  .x(d => d.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2)
  .y(d => d.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2);

/* 
    Function that creates the first tree with the default layout
*/
function createRoot() {
  // Data is already in JSON format. We only need to create the hierarchy
  // based on it.
  let root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  root.x0 = DX / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;
  root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
    d.id = i;
    d._children = d.children;
    if (d.depth >= 0) d.children = null;
  });
  return root;
}

/* 
    Function that updates all the nodes in a tree according to the click event
*/
function update(source) {
  const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
  const links = root.links();

  // Compute the new tree layout
  tree(root);

  const transition = svg.transition()
    .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
    .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));

  /*=============================NODE SECTION============================== */
  // Obtain all the nodes
  const node = gNode.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes, d => d.id);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x0},${source.y0})`)
    .on("click", function(event, d) {
      if (d.children) // Node expanded -> Collapse
        collapse(d);
      else // Node collapsed -> Expand
        d.children = d._children
      update(d);
      centerNode(d);
    })

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    // Two different classes, one for the links that can be expanded and
    // another for the expanded ones or leafs.
    .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded")
    .attr("height", RECT_HEIGHT)
    .attr("width", RECT_WIDTH)

  // Inside node text
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    // The position of the text is centered 
    .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
    .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
    // Text of the node is the name. This will change in future versions
    // to handle all the data that we want to store
    .text(d => d.data.name)
    .clone(true).lower();

  // Transition nodes to their new position (update)
  var nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition(transition)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
    // Smooth transition from 0 to 1 and back to 0 when expanding/collapsing
    .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);

  // Update class of rectangles
  nodeUpdate.select('rect')
    .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded");

  /*  Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position (that's why we use
      x and y instead of x0 and y0) */
  node.exit().transition(transition).remove()
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x},${source.y})`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

  /*=============================LINK SECTION============================== */
  const link = gLink.selectAll("path")
    .data(links, d => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position
  const linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
    .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)") // add the arrow to the link end
    // d attribute defines a path to be drawn
    .attr("d", d => {
      const o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      // Diagonal actually paints a curve line between the source and the
      // target
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position
  link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition)
    // In this case the link will be changed in order to have the arrows in
    // the correct position 
    .attr("d", d => diagonal({
      source: d.source,
      target: {
        x: d.target.x,
        y: d.target.y - RECT_HEIGHT
      }
    }));

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
  link.exit().transition(transition).remove()
    .attr("d", d => {
      const o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  const linkText = gLink.selectAll("g")
    .data(links, d => d.target.id);

  const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "linkLabel")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${source.x0 + RECT_WIDTH / 2},${source.y0 + RECT_HEIGHT / 2})`)

  linkTextEnter.append("text")
    .text(d => (d.target.data.link));

  linkText.merge(linkTextEnter).transition(transition)
    .attr("transform", d =>
      `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x + RECT_WIDTH) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`)
    // Smooth transition from 0 to 1 and back to 0 when expanding/collapsing
    .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);

  linkText.exit().transition(transition).remove()
    .attr("transform", `translate(${source.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2},${source.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2})`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

  // Stash the old positions for transition
  root.eachBefore(d => {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

/*
    Function that centers a given node in the screen. It will be used so that
    the node that has been clicked doesn't go out of sight
*/
function centerNode(source) {
  let scale = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("svg").node()).k;
  let x = -source.x0 * scale + width / 2 - RECT_WIDTH / 2 * scale;
  let y = -source.y0 * scale + height / 2 - RECT_HEIGHT / 2 * scale;
  // Define the transition
  const transition = svg.transition()
    .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
    .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));
  // Move all the nodes based on the previous parameters
  svg.transition(transition)
    .call(zoomBehaviours.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x, y).scale(scale));
}

/*
    Function that collapses all the subtree of a given node.
*/
function collapse(node) {
  if (node.children) { // Expanded
    node.children = null;
    node._children.forEach(collapse)
  }
}

/*
    Function that creates the possibility to add arrows to links
*/
function createArrows() {
  defs.selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("marker") // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 10 10`)
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
}

// Root creation
const root = createRoot();

// SVG variable that will contain all the configuration for the images.
// We need to append it to the body
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// SVG group that will contain two groups declared below
const g = svg.append("g");

// Two groups: One of links and another of nodes
const gLink = g.append("g");
const gNode = g.append("g");

// Zoom configuration
const zoomBehaviours = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM])
  .on('zoom', (event) => g.attr('transform', event.transform));

// Add the zoom so that svg knows that it is available
svg.call(zoomBehaviours);

// build the arrow.
let defs = svg.append("svg:defs");
createArrows();

// We need to update the root first to generate the first tree, and center it
update(root);
centerNode(root);
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node .notExpanded {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.2;
  fill: lightskyblue;
}

.node .expanded {
  fill: lightskyblue;
}

.node text {
  fill: black;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-align: center;
  alignment-baseline: central;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

.linkLabel {
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
  font: 8px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: central;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: grab;
}

body:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/main.js"></script>

</html>
```